# Sources for iPad web programming?

Tags: css, ipad, safari, mobile-safari

Anyone got some good references for targeting web content to the iPad web browser? i know its still very early days but I havent got any good indicator on how to setup CSS to fix iphone/ipod touch versus the larger screen of the iPad? or do I just consider it to be like safari on the bigger Macs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Safari for iPad is a hybrid between the desktop version of Safari and the Mobile iPhone version.

For example it supports inline video like the desktop, but scrollable div's are difficult for users to interact with just like the iPhone. (they require two fingers to scroll, which is not discoverable.

[Preparing your Content For iPad](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2010/tn2262/_index.html) is a good place to start, and the iPad Simulator is now a free download as part of the [iPhone SDK](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/).

Comment: +1 "they require two fingers to scroll, which is not discoverable" Very true, I've had my iPhone for a year and I didn't know this until I read this answer. This knowledge makes SO much more usable on the iPhone. I think SO should detect iOS devices and inform the user of this feature.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't get the SDK to play with, 9to5 Mac posted a video of Safari in the iPad simulator: [iPad Safari walthrough](http://9to5mac.com/ipad-safari-walkthru-video-4650470). They seem to think it's closer to Safari on a mac and Google doesn't look like it does on an iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the apple webpage, seems that Safari will be the iPad's browser.

[Source](http://9to5mac.com/ipad-safari-walkthru-video-4650470).

Comment: but its not clear from the SDK if its going to be mobile safari or safari on my mac book. if I target the iphone via css its going to set up a  320x480 dispaly. this isnt going to work well with a high resolution iPad 1024x768 display. I guess I will find out on saturday when I pick up my unit

Comment: Yeah, I see where it's not clear, hope you find out on Saturday, then hopefully you'll know. I hope it's the real Safari and not the phone version. Why have a phone browser on a tablet like unit?

Answer (score 1):

check out this jQuery plugin that handles touch events on web apps such as scaling, rotation and wiping. Hope it will make your life a bit easier.

http://desmondliang.com/content/touchme-jquery-plugin-ipad-web-apps